# where is the misatake in deformation retract?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In one textbook, it use formula below to prove $S^1$ is a [strong deformation retract](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongDeformationRetract.html) of $R^2-\{(0,0)\}$
$$
h(x,t)=\frac{x}{(1-t)+t\|x\|}
$$
but I found using the  the same formula can also prove $S^1$ is a  strong deformation retract of $R^2-\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Certainly, it is not right, but I cannot find where the mistake is. can you tell why this formula fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is $h((\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2),\sqrt 2-1)$?